# Replace NULL with 0 in Pivot Table combined with avg CAST

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, pivot-table, isnull

I'm trying to replace NULL to 0 in the output of my TagValue column combined with avg Cast.
I tried the following query:

```
ISNULL(TRY_CAST(TagValue AS DECIMAL(18,2)),0) AS TagValue
```

in the code

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(TagID)
                      FROM [table]
                      GROUP BY TagID
                      ORDER BY TagID
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')

SET @query = 'SELECT   TimeStamp,  ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select  DATEADD(minute,DATEDIFF(minute,0,TimeStamp)/5*5,0) AS  TimeStamp, TagID ,   ISNULL(TRY_CAST(TagValue AS DECIMAL(18,2)),0) AS TagValue 
                from [table]
                 -- Where TagValue isnull(TagValue,1)=0
                Group By datediff(minute, 0,Timestamp)/5,TagID, TagValue
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                AVG(TagValue)
                for TagID in ( ' + @cols + ' )
            ) p '

EXEC(@query)
```

although there are no errors the query output keeps showing NULL.

I also tried the following queries:

```
SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT  ','', IsNull(' + QUOTENAME(TagID)+', 0) as '+QUOTENAME(TagID)
                      FROM [table]
                      GROUP BY TagID
                      ORDER BY TagID
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')
...
```

```
SET @query = 'SELECT TimeStamp,  ' +ISNULL(@cols,0) + ' from ...
```

Also the Case function:

```
CASE When (TagValue= NULL) THEN 0 ELSE TRY_CAST(TagValue AS DECIMAL(18,2)) END AS TagValue
```

Would very appreciate your help!
Thanks a lot

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: SQL server management studio 2018

Comment: Instead of `CASE When (TagValue= NULL)`, try `CASE When TagValue IS NULL`

Comment: You need to use 2 different `@cols`, one that has the `ISNULL` and will be used on the select column list and another without the null checks that you will use on the pivot.

Comment: `coalesce( TRY_CAST(TagValue AS DECIMAL(18,2) ), 0) AS TagValue`

Comment: That worked great! can you explain a bit more why it doesn't work with only 1 col? @EzLo

Answer (score 1):

The `PIVOT` operator works on a set of constant values. These values must be explicitly written and can't be reference to another columns, contain expressions or functions like `ISNULL`.

```
DECLARE @Mascot TABLE (
    Amount INT,
    Mascot VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @Mascot (
    Amount,
    Mascot)
VALUES
    (10, 'Dog'), (5, 'Dog'),
    (6, 'Cat'),
    (12, 'Weird Spider'), (8, 'Weird Spider'), (5, 'Weird Spider')

SELECT
    P.*
FROM
    @Mascot AS M
    PIVOT (
        SUM(M.Amount)
        FOR Mascot IN ([Dog], [Cat], [Weird Spider], [Cameleon])
    ) AS P
```

Result:

```
Dog     Cat     Weird Spider    Cameleon
15      6       25              NULL
```

After the table is pivoted, these constant values are now ***columns***, with their name as the constant we used to pivot them:

```
SELECT
    P.Dog, -- We can reference the pivoted columns by name
    P.Cat,
    P.[Weird Spider],
    P.Cameleon
FROM
    @Mascot AS M
    PIVOT (
        SUM(M.Amount)
        FOR Mascot IN ([Dog], [Cat], [Weird Spider], [Cameleon])
    ) AS P
```

We can do any modification we want as an expression on the `SELECT` column list:

```
SELECT
    P.Dog,
    P.Cat,
    P.[Weird Spider],
    ISNULL(P.Cameleon, 0) AS Cameleon,
    Total = 
        ISNULL(P.Dog, 0) +
        ISNULL(P.Cat, 0) +
        ISNULL(P.[Weird Spider], 0) +
        ISNULL(P.Cameleon, 0)
FROM
    @Mascot AS M
    PIVOT (
        SUM(M.Amount)
        FOR Mascot IN ([Dog], [Cat], [Weird Spider], [Cameleon])
    ) AS P
```

Result:

```
Dog     Cat     Weird Spider    Cameleon    Total
15      6       25              0           46
```

So when you build your dynamic pivot, the pivot values must be the exact content of the value stored in the set that you are gonna pivot (`'Dog'`, `'Cat'`, etc.), while on the `SELECT` list you can build any expression you want (`ISNULL([Dog], 0) AS [Dog]`).

---

So the solution for your case is to use 2 different `@cols`, one with the null checks on the `SELECT` list and another to pivot the values.

```
DECLARE @cols_select AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @cols_pivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols_pivot = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(TagID)
                      FROM [table]
                      GROUP BY TagID
                      ORDER BY TagID
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')

SELECT @cols_select = STUFF((SELECT  ','', IsNull(' + QUOTENAME(TagID)+', 0) as '+QUOTENAME(TagID)
                      FROM [table]
                      GROUP BY TagID
                      ORDER BY TagID
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')

SET @query = 'SELECT   TimeStamp,  ' + @cols_select + ' from 
             (
                select  DATEADD(minute,DATEDIFF(minute,0,TimeStamp)/5*5,0) AS  TimeStamp, TagID ,   ISNULL(TRY_CAST(TagValue AS DECIMAL(18,2)),0) AS TagValue 
                from [table]
                 -- Where TagValue isnull(TagValue,1)=0
                Group By datediff(minute, 0,Timestamp)/5,TagID, TagValue
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                AVG(TagValue)
                for TagID in ( ' + @cols_pivot + ' )
            ) p '

EXEC(@query)
```